# Two Site Themes

Tags: theming, nodes

PROBLEM: Drupal 6 website developed with customized theme. Blog module does not play well with customized theme.

POSSIBLE SOLUTION: Would it be possible to set up a directory called /blog and load the Drupal BlogBuzz II theme? It needs to use the existing main website DB so searches on the main website will also return blog content.

Is this possible and if so are there any resources online that describe the process?

P.S. Thought about using WordPress as a sub-site but then Search queries on the main website will not return content in the WordPress Blog website.

Thanks-in-Advance,

John

Answer (score 3):

You can use ThemeKey to achieve this (https://drupal.org/project/themekey). It will allow you to use a second, tailored theme, in specific places, like for a specific content type.

Comment: One more question if I may. I used themekey and switched to a blog theme based on the directory (/blog). But how do I remove all of the main website navigation menu's, sidebars, etc..?

Comment: I got most of what I need working however, I would like to display different links in the main menu when users are on my blog theme vs. main website theme. I there an easy way to do this?

Comment: My main website uses the Drupal Menu system, for main nav. links, and not Blocks . If I select Primary Navigation in my Drupal Blog theme all of my main website links show up on the Blog main Nav which I do not want. Basically, I want the Main Nav. on the Blog to have different links than the Main Nav. on the main website.

Comment: You can use the block setting to hide the nav on specific pages

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install another module (or don't need something super fancy), you can do something like this in your `sites/default/settings.php` file:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog')===0) {
  $conf['theme_default'] = 'blogbuzzii'; // or whatever it's called
}
```

and every page path that starts with `/blog` should now be themed with the `blogbuzzii` theme.